# How get a headless Debian server on a laptop to switch off the screen but keep running when lid is closed?

Tags: debian, systemd, power-management, laptop, logind

I'm running a headless (no GUI, no desktop environment) Debian server on a laptop. I would like it to switch off the screen but keep running when lid is closed. I already tried setting `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, but that doesn't turn off the screen when the lid is closed. Instead, it ignores the lid closing action completely. How can I get the laptop screen to turn off when lid is closed?